# webbrowser using ie10 c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, registry

I want to force the webbrowser to use IE10 in my c# winform application.
I know there are other questions like this but i've already read a lot of them and i don't know where i'm wrong.

This is my code:

```
RegistryKey registrybrowser = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey
           (@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
        registrybrowser.SetValue("myAppName", 0x02710, RegistryValueKind.DWord); //Even with QWord
```

I've tried different ways to set the value like:

```
registrybrowser.SetValue("myAppName", 1000, RegistryValueKind.DWord); //Even with QWord and String
registrybrowser.SetValue("myAppName", 1000); //even with 0x02710
```

I write it in the costructor of my main project before InitializeComponent().
I've got Admin permission set in the .manifest file

Thanks to all, BlackShawarna

EDIT: I discovered that the RegistryKey.SetValue(...); created a key in another path:

```
(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION")
```

even if my instruction said: `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey
               (@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);`

I think it happens because IE10 works on 32bit mode. However I don't understand why it writes in that path even if i specified another one and, above all, why my application doesn't work even if I open Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Wow6432Node....");

If I run my program only in x64 mode, going to properties/build/x64, it won't write the key in my original path.

Comment: Have you tried to set it manually to make sure it works in the first place?

Comment: Do you have x86 or x64?

Comment: windows 8 x64. However now i tried to set it manually and it doesn't work. Yesterday, before to implement the code in c#, the registry key (set manually) worked well. Is it possible because I don't write registrybrowser.Close() when my program closed? Could I "clean" the registry?

Comment: Possibly your changes won't be committed / flushed if you don't `close`... You will need to look manually for your entries or try a registry cleaner...

Comment: Be sure that the Platform target setting on your EXE project is AnyCPU and not x86.  Or you'll write the wrong registry key.  It also matters what version of IE you've got installed and whether it might be used in 32-bit mode in some programs.  Review the .NET 4+ RegistryView type.

Comment: @HansPassant Useful answer, I added some details.

Comment: You would imagine that MS would at least make it easy to use IE with .NET...!!!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem that my app wrote the value to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION".

I changed LocalMachine to CurrentUser and now it works.

```
string executablePath = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0];
string executableName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(executablePath);

RegistryKey registrybrowser = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
   (@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);

if (registrybrowser == null)
{
    RegistryKey registryFolder = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
        (@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl", true);
    registrybrowser = registryFolder.CreateSubKey("FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION");
}
registrybrowser.SetValue(executableName, 0x02710, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
registrybrowser.Close();
```

The executableName is something like "myAppName.exe"

Note: If the WebBrowser Controls inside a DLL you need to specify the hosting EXE's name whatever that might be, eg `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName`

Answer (score 3):

`FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` `"myAppName.exe"=10000` (or 0x02710) and not 1000.

In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`

and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

You've got to say 'myAppName.exe'  not 'myAppName'

Answer (score 0):

*If* you have control over the page being rendered (a intranet page for instance) and also of the application that renders the page using the WebBrowser control, you can specify a meta tag in the page

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

and make use of the WebBrowser control as needed. You must have IE 10 on the machine.

Just in case you want to emulate other versions of IE, you could simply replace `"IE=10"` with `"IE=EmulateIE9"`, `"IE=EmulateIE8"` etc.